# Magento2 - HDFC CC Avenue Payment Gateway

Tags: magento2, magento2ccavenue

I am new to Magento and I was developing the site with HDFC Payment gateway installed the extension given by HDFC bank but I got error sometimes.

Sometimes It goes back to success page but sometimes It takes me to there has been an error processing your request page.

I haven't changed anything in Magento core or extension also, there is no `log` in `exception.log`.

Help me to solve thank you!

Comment: what error showing ??? share Please

Comment: there has been an error processing your request
it shows this error on-page
can't see any changes in exception.log

Answer (score 0):

I integrated HDFC CC Avenue Payment Gateway on my domain and it's working properly because some configuration is required for a mode like a test or live mode

First check HDFC nodal account credential is a live mode or test mode. As per credential set configuration correctly.

- Merchant Id
- Access Code
- Encryption key

These is my configurations.

[image]